# Selecionar maior valor de uma lista // Python

Tags: python

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Preciso criar um programa que leia uma lista aleatória de valores positivos e negativos, e retorne o maior valor. Como solução, já tentei utilizar while, if e a função max(), mas nenhuma destas está funcionando.

Com a funão max() por exemplo, meu código está deste jeito:

> **lista1 = client.recv(2048)** // recebo a lista aleatória do servidor
>
> **print lista1** // escrevo a lista na tela
>
> **resposta = max(lista1)** // calculando o valor máximo da lista
>
> **print resposta** // escrevo a resposta na tela
>
> **client.send(resposta)** // envio a resposta para o servidor

Como resultado, estou obtendo o seguinte:

> **[4367859, 9736628, -530197, -5556671, 8246498, 3478110, -8101840, 3049971, 9121277, -4665343]** // lista aleatória que é gerada pelo
>   servidor
>
> **]** // resultado de "resposta", ou seja, valor que foi enviado para o servidor
>
> **Errou, tente novamente.** //resposta do servidor informando que o valor inserido não está correto

Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo errado? ou se tem alguma outra solução para escrever este código?

Agradeço desde já, abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Ao receber a informação do servidor com a função `recv()` seus dados chegam no formato de uma string.

Testei isso por meio do código:

```py
lista1 = "[4367859, 9736628, -530197, -5556671, 8246498, 3478110, -8101840, 3049971, 9121277, -4665343]"
print lista1

resposta = max(lista1)
print resposta
```

Para resolver isso usei:

```py
resposta = lista1.split(",")
for i in range(0,len(resposta)):
    resposta[i] = resposta[i].strip("[")
    resposta[i] = resposta[i].strip("]")
```

Usando a função `split` separei a string recebida em cada caractere `,` e depois usando a função `strip` removi os colchetes.

Rodando o programa, recebi então a seguinte resposta:

```py
['4367859', ' 9736628', ' -530197', ' -5556671', ' 8246498', ' 3478110', ' -8101840', ' 3049971', ' 9121277', ' -4665343']
```

mostrando que agora o objeto é uma lista e permitindo então que se use a função `max()`.

Usando seu código, a solução para seu problema seria:

```py
lista1 = client.recv(2048) // recebo a lista aleatória do servidor

lista1 = lista1.split(",")
for i in range(0,len(resposta)):
    resposta[i] = resposta[i].strip("[")
    resposta[i] = resposta[i].strip("]")

print lista1 // escrevo a lista na tela

resposta = max(lista1) // calculando o valor máximo da lista

print resposta // escrevo a resposta na tela

client.send(resposta) // envio a resposta para o servidor
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!!!